# how to intercept the web request of a remote machine in a LAN

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, fiddler, wireshark, burp

i am using so many tool like burpsuite  but with this tool I can capture the local host traffic only can any body tell me that how to intercept the web request of a remote machine

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be achievable with fiddler:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/monitorremotemachine

Comment: but  can we change the request header with fiddler. like i intercept the request and change it with burp suite but burp suite is only for localhost I want to intercept the remote system request and change it

Comment: Fiddler main page: "Easily manipulate and edit web sessions. All you need to do is set a breakpoint to pause the processing of the session and permit alteration of the request/response. You can also compose your own HTTP requests to run through Fiddler." If you wanna know if it supports the functionality you searching for please check the fiddler documentation on their main page